# Assignment is not recognized when parsing AST tree

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I have the following code:

```
package testpackage;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class TestClass 
 {  
    private static int a = 0;
    public void test1() 
     {
       int b = a + 1;
       int c = 3;
    }       
 }
```

I parse that with a an `ASTVisitor` object:

```
final CompilationUnit compilationUnit = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);
compilationUnit.accept(new ASTVisitor() 
 {

   @Override
   public boolean visit(Assignment node) 
   {
      System.out.println("assignment");
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) 
   {
      System.out.println("type");
      return true;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) 
   {
      System.out.println("method");
      return true;
   }

    //more code here
};
```

The parsing works find for the type and method declaration, but not for the assignment. In my opinion there are 3 assignments in my example code. But why does the ASTVisitor object not recognize them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

All of the three expressions you mentioned are *not* assignment expressions. This is why the corresponding *visit* is not executed.

To clarify it, the first expression is a [`FieldDeclaration`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/FieldDeclaration.html). The other two are [`VariableDeclarationStatement`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/VariableDeclarationStatement.html)s. All three are containing [`VariableDeclarationFragment`](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/VariableDeclarationFragment.html)s.

That means you should add the following methods with which you can see the parse process:

```
public boolean visit(FieldDeclaration node) {
    System.out.println("field declaration: " + node);
    return true;
}

public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationStatement node) {
    System.out.println("variable declaration: " + node);
    return true;
}
```